# Wildfly 9.0.2.Final: "IOP00410216: (COMM_FAILURE) Unable to create listener thread on the specified port: 3529"

Tags: java, startup, wildfly-9, iiop, wildfly-cluster

I have a Wildfly cluster as described on [this blog post](https://deventerpriselog.blogspot.com/2017/02/making-javaee-ecosystem-work-how-we.html). I recently updated the datasource to the new HA MS SQL Server cluster we have and restarted our entire, specific server (using the Linux Service we created).

Unfortunately, the error I encounter is valid in all the server groups found in the same physical server. This error is:

```
2017-05-22 13:36:56,560 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.corba._DEFAULT_.rpc.transport] (MSC service thread 1-1) "IOP00410216: (COMM_FAILURE) Unable to create listener thread on the specified port: 3529": org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 216  completed: No
```

I have tried various means to make it work including killing the process that runs on port 3529 but to no avail.

Port 3529 the socket binding for "iiop-ssl" (see domain.xml for reference).

How do I resolve this problem? The various solutions found online don't seem to work for my case.

The full stacktrace:

```
2017-05-22 13:36:38,496 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
2017-05-22 13:36:39,354 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
2017-05-22 13:36:39,978 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) starting
2017-05-22 13:36:39,980 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-4) Configured system properties:
    [Server:kanban-qa-server] = 
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = /
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
    java.class.path = /opt/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
    java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
    java.runtime.name = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_121-b13
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_121
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.121-b13
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
    javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
    jboss.ajp.port = 8009
    jboss.bind.address = 0.0.0.0
    jboss.bind.address.management = 0.0.0.0
    jboss.domain.base.dir = /opt/wildfly/domain
    jboss.domain.config.dir = /opt/wildfly/domain/configuration
    jboss.home.dir = /opt/wildfly
    jboss.host.name = sv-wfqa
    jboss.http.port = 8080
    jboss.https.port = 8443
    jboss.management.http.port = 9990
    jboss.management.https.port = 9993
    jboss.modules.dir = /opt/wildfly/modules
    jboss.node.name = sv-wfqa:kanban-qa-server
    jboss.qualified.host.name = sv-wfqa.supergrp.net
    jboss.server.base.dir = /opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server
    jboss.server.config.dir = /opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = /opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/data
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = /opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/data/content
    jboss.server.log.dir = /opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/log
    jboss.server.name = kanban-qa-server
    jboss.server.persist.config = true
    jboss.server.temp.dir = /opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/tmp
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/data/logging.properties
    module.path = /opt/wildfly/modules
    org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
    org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Linux
    os.version = 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64
    path.separator = :
    spring.profiles.active = qa
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/classes
    sun.boot.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = 
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = /opt/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/wildfly/modules org.jboss.as.server
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = unknown
    user.country = ZA
    user.dir = /opt/wildfly
    user.home = /home/wildfly
    user.language = en
    user.name = wildfly
    user.timezone = Africa/Johannesburg
2017-05-22 13:36:39,983 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-4) VM Arguments: -D[Server:kanban-qa-server] -Dspring.profiles.active=qa -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.ajp.port=8009 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/wildfly -Djboss.http.port=8080 -Djboss.https.port=8443 -Djboss.management.http.port=9990 -Djboss.management.https.port=9993 -Djboss.server.log.dir=/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/log -Djboss.server.temp.dir=/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/tmp -Djboss.server.data.dir=/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/data -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/data/logging.properties 
2017-05-22 13:36:40,212 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
2017-05-22 13:36:40,234 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
2017-05-22 13:36:40,345 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
2017-05-22 13:36:47,428 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'job-repository-type' in the resource at address '/subsystem=batch' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-05-22 13:36:47,451 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-05-22 13:36:47,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=Supercare2DevDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-05-22 13:36:47,476 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=Supercare2QADS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-05-22 13:36:47,477 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KanbanQADS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-05-22 13:36:47,478 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=Supercare2PreProdDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-05-22 13:36:47,479 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=vldmDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-05-22 13:36:47,480 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KanbanDevDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-05-22 13:36:47,481 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=vldmXADS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-05-22 13:36:48,946 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
2017-05-22 13:36:48,990 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
2017-05-22 13:36:50,192 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.2.Final
2017-05-22 13:36:50,183 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
2017-05-22 13:36:50,202 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 4 core threads with 32 task threads based on your 2 available processors
2017-05-22 13:36:50,278 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
2017-05-22 13:36:50,352 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
2017-05-22 13:36:50,385 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
2017-05-22 13:36:50,409 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
2017-05-22 13:36:50,355 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
2017-05-22 13:36:50,563 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
2017-05-22 13:36:50,541 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
2017-05-22 13:36:50,664 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYIIOP0001: Activating IIOP Subsystem
2017-05-22 13:36:51,157 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
2017-05-22 13:36:51,275 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:/mail/vldmMailSession]
2017-05-22 13:36:51,426 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
2017-05-22 13:36:51,536 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:/mail/expressMailSession]
2017-05-22 13:36:52,363 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 6.0)
2017-05-22 13:36:52,412 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYJCA0086: Unable to find driver class name in "ojdbc14" jar
2017-05-22 13:36:52,469 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path /opt/wildfly/welcome-content
2017-05-22 13:36:52,400 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.2.5.Final)
2017-05-22 13:36:52,844 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
2017-05-22 13:36:52,958 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql
2017-05-22 13:36:52,951 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = sqlserver
2017-05-22 13:36:53,391 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
2017-05-22 13:36:53,616 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
2017-05-22 13:36:54,534 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /0.0.0.0:8081
2017-05-22 13:36:56,141 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYIIOP0009: CORBA ORB Service started
2017-05-22 13:36:56,385 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/VldmXADS]
2017-05-22 13:36:56,386 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/supercare2PREPRODDS]
2017-05-22 13:36:56,386 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/supercare2QADS]
2017-05-22 13:36:56,386 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2017-05-22 13:36:56,576 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/supercare2DevDS]
2017-05-22 13:36:56,576 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/VLDM_DS]
2017-05-22 13:36:56,577 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/kanbanQADS]
2017-05-22 13:36:56,560 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.corba._DEFAULT_.rpc.transport] (MSC service thread 1-1) "IOP00410216: (COMM_FAILURE) Unable to create listener thread on the specified port: 3529": org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 216  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2632)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2651)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:164)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.getAcceptors(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:217)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.addToIORTemplate(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.corba.se.spi.oa.ObjectAdapterBase.initializeTemplate(ObjectAdapterBase.java:122)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.initialize(POAImpl.java:404)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.makeRootPOA(POAImpl.java:272)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.oa.poa.POAFactory$1.evaluate(POAFactory.java:205)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.closure.Future.evaluate(Future.java:46)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.LocalResolverImpl.resolve(LocalResolverImpl.java:40)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:45)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1171)
    at org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk.service.CorbaPOAService.start(CorbaPOAService.java:156)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:161)
    ... 16 more

2017-05-22 13:36:56,590 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa: WFLYIIOP0098: Failed to resolve initial reference RootPOA
    at org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk.service.CorbaPOAService.start(CorbaPOAService.java:158)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 216  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2632)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2651)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:164)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.getAcceptors(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:217)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.addToIORTemplate(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.corba.se.spi.oa.ObjectAdapterBase.initializeTemplate(ObjectAdapterBase.java:122)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.initialize(POAImpl.java:404)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.makeRootPOA(POAImpl.java:272)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.oa.poa.POAFactory$1.evaluate(POAFactory.java:205)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.closure.Future.evaluate(Future.java:46)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.LocalResolverImpl.resolve(LocalResolverImpl.java:40)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:45)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1171)
    at org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk.service.CorbaPOAService.start(CorbaPOAService.java:156)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:161)
    ... 16 more

2017-05-22 13:36:56,609 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/kanbanDEVDS]
2017-05-22 13:36:57,043 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HQ221000: live server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=false,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/data/messagingjournal,bindingsDirectory=/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/data/messagingbindings,largeMessagesDirectory=/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/data/messaginglargemessages,pagingDirectory=/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/kanban-qa-server/data/messagingpaging)
2017-05-22 13:36:57,262 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HQ221006: Waiting to obtain live lock
2017-05-22 13:36:57,093 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 5.0.0.Final
2017-05-22 13:36:57,431 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HQ221012: Using AIO Journal
2017-05-22 13:36:59,395 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HQ221043: Adding protocol support CORE
2017-05-22 13:36:59,400 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HQ221043: Adding protocol support AMQP
2017-05-22 13:36:59,487 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HQ221043: Adding protocol support STOMP
2017-05-22 13:36:59,987 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HQ221034: Waiting to obtain live lock
2017-05-22 13:36:59,987 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
2017-05-22 13:37:02,067 INFO  [org.jboss.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMSG0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for hornetq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
2017-05-22 13:37:02,067 INFO  [org.jboss.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMSG0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for hornetq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
2017-05-22 13:37:03,049 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HQ221007: Server is now live
2017-05-22 13:37:03,061 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HQ221001: HornetQ Server version 2.4.7.Final (2.4.7.Final, 124) [e47d0f39-ec62-11e6-8282-9791a651bb9c] 
2017-05-22 13:37:03,177 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
2017-05-22 13:37:03,919 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
2017-05-22 13:37:03,982 INFO  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HQ121005: Invalid "host" value "0.0.0.0" detected for "http-connector" connector. Switching to "sv-wfqa.supergrp.net". If this new address is incorrect please manually configure the connector to use the proper one.
2017-05-22 13:37:04,019 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYMSG0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
2017-05-22 13:37:04,050 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYMSG0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
2017-05-22 13:37:04,055 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
2017-05-22 13:37:04,456 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (MSC service thread 1-3) HornetQ resource adaptor started
2017-05-22 13:37:04,457 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-3) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
2017-05-22 13:37:04,459 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
2017-05-22 13:37:04,459 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMSG0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
2017-05-22 13:37:04,462 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "iiop-openjdk")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa: WFLYIIOP0098: Failed to resolve initial reference RootPOA
    Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 216  completed: No
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use"}}
2017-05-22 13:37:04,849 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa: WFLYIIOP0098: Failed to resolve initial reference RootPOA

2017-05-22 13:37:06,174 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) started (with errors) in 28568ms - Started 267 of 446 services (4 services failed or missing dependencies, 220 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As written on the following article: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/300823
You need to change the `jboss.bind.address.unsecure` address in order to work properly.

You might want to use the `-Djboss.bind.address.unsecure` argument.